# circle inside circle using imageview

Tags: android

I am using two imageviews with circle png for each one, now on my phone (s6 edge) the two images are perfectly set, one inside the other,
here is my xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/outter"
        android:layout_height="405dp"
        android:layout_width="405dp"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/inner"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrowbb"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

now if I run the app on galaxy s2 foe example, I get the two circle almost covering each other, not the way it was on s6 edge, although I use the dp to set the width and height for each imageviews as shown in the xml.

note that the both circle images I used here in the imageview is 32 bit, and I used photoshop to resize it.

I need the two circles to be the same shape on any android phone, how to that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/outter"
    android:layout_height="405dp"
    android:layout_width="405dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/inner"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/arrowbb"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/outter"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/outter"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/outter"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/outter"  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it worked thats the answer:D ,thanks alot man), answer accepted